# Query the last 30 days + last 60 days + "true"

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Given table login_logs with columns UserName (Varchar), LoginDate (Datetime), was successful (Boolean).  Write a query that will return UserName, # of times user successfully logged in last 30 days, # of times user successfully logged in last 60 days

```
SELECT UserName, LoginDate, was_successful
FROM login_logs
WHERE LoginDate >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
AND LoginDate >= DATEADD(day,-60,GETDATE())
AND was_successful = 'true';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using `LoginDate >= ` twice! Try: `WHERE LoginDate <= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE()) AND LoginDate >= DATEADD(day,-60,GETDATE()`

Comment: Show expected output

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where clause needs to filter for dates greater than `today - 60 days` which also covers `today - 30 days`. Then use conditional aggregation:

```
select username
     , last_60 = count(*)
     , last_30 = count(case when logindate >= dateadd(day, -30, cast(current_timestamp as date)) then 1 end)
from login_logs
where logindate >= dateadd(day, -60, cast(current_timestamp as date)) and was_successful = 'true'
group by username
```